# Cambiar el user-agent con el que el dom hace las peticiones

Tags: php, html, dom, curl, video

Estoy tratando de visualizar un streaming con la libreria "[VideoJs](https://videojs.com/)".
Mi problema es que para visualizar el streaming el servidor checa que el user-agent que esta realizando la petición sea "x", de lo contrario no me lo reproduce.
Si cambio el user-agent con la ayuda del complemento "[User-Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/uaswitcher/)" para Firefox entonces la condición se cumple y me deja reproducirlo.
Este es mi codigo con el que estoy tratando de reproducirlo.

```
index.php
```

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Get Video Channel User-Agent</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.2.1 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- VideoJS || Require JS -->
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.5/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/videojsSkin.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container no-gutters">
        <div class="row justify-content-left">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-lg-center">
                    <video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin col-md-12" width="100%" height="400px" data-setup ='{}' controls preload="none" 
                    poster='./images/poster.jpg'>
                        <source src="http://example.com/video.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JQuery 3.3.1 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.2.1 -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- VideoJS || Requiere CSS -->
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.5/video.js"></script>
    <script src="js/videojsEspanol.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Trate de realizar una petición a través de cURL hacia el streaming cambiando el user-agent con la que hago la petición y luego apuntar el source del video hacia mi petición cURL y efectivamente la realiza; El problema de esta solución es que al tratar de acceder a los datos de reproducción alojados en el host de destino el reproductor trata de buscar esos datos dentro de mi propio host.
Para que se den una idea el log del reproductor vlc me arroja estos datos de error.

Failed reading http://localhost:80/Streaming/cURL.php/l_8192161_109998777_1.ts?nimblesessionid=36907950: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Cuando lo que tendría que tratar de leer esta ubicado en:
http://example.com/video.m3u8/l_8192161_109998777_1.ts?nimblesessionid=36907950

Otra manera que se me ocurrio es poder cambiar el user-agent con el que el dom carga el/los archivos cuando lee la etiqueta "src" (de ahi el titulo del post). Pero no estoy muy seguro de como hacer esto y de igual manera no se si se pueda.

Estoy abierto a sugerencias o nuevas ideas.

Al igual trate de modificar el userAgent con javascript de esta manera:

```
        navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () {
            return "BrzLRzQgfTrvXYGnfIVrkwb9402QA44LkyZf98xmMznUT"
        });

        var videoDom = $('<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin col-md-12" width="100%" height="400px" data-setup ="{}" controls preload="none" poster="image.php"/>', {
            id: 'video',
        });
        videoDom.appendTo($('#divVideo'));

        var chapter = $('<source>', {
            src: './VideoStream.php',
            type: 'video/mp4'
        });
        chapter.appendTo(videoDom);
```

Buscando que primero me actualizara la información del userAgent y luego me hiciera la petición pero en el log de  "VideoStream.php" sigue indicando que el archivo fue llamado desde el userAgent original.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa sería usar algo como:

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {
    get: function () { return 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; 
    rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0)'; }
});
```

Sin embargo, no es lo óptimo que cambies el User-Agent en el HTML ya que el HTML es el mensaje, no el mensajero.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44367690/7737267

Comment: Trate de implementarlo pero la petición hacia el video me la sigue haciendo con el userAgent original.